# Magento 2 : new class not able to add in override construct method

Tags: magento2

i have override this class `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add`
but i need to add additional class in construct method like below

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
        CustomerCart $cart,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurableProduct
    ) {

        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $scopeConfig,
            $checkoutSession,
            $storeManager,
            $formKeyValidator,
            $cart
        );
    $this->configurableProduct = $configurableProduct;
    }
```

I have use this class additionally `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable`

but still showing below error:

```
{"0":"Missing required argument $context of Dynamic\\Checkout\\Controller\\Index\\Cart.","1":"<pre>#1 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->_resolveArguments('Dynamic\\Checkout...', array(array('context', NULL, true, NULL),
```

i have already tried to upgrade. deploy, compile command but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution!

Issue was, i have not declare below class in my override method that's why its throwing a error.

```
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
```